# Regex to parse image markdown to image html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, markdown

Im using this expression: https://regex101.com/r/kWhBYU/1/

```
Regex: !\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)
Substitution "<img alt='$1' src='$2' />"
```

to replace this image in markdown:

```
![image (2).png](https://dev.azure.com/image.png)
```

to image in html

```
"<img alt='image (2).png' src='https://dev.azure.com/image.png' />"
```

And everything works perfect, but theres an issue then the markdown image name change to **"image%20(2).png"**

From this markdown

```
![image (2).png](https://dev.azure.com/image%20(2).png)
```

i get this html

```
"<img alt='image (2).png' src='https://dev.azure.com/image%20(2' />".png)
```

This issue is being cause by the "**(2)**" parenthesis in the regex.
Is there a regex that can apply to both case scenario?

Comment: Seems like you'd need a stack/recursion/real parser to catch this reliably. Consider `[foo](bar(4(5(6)7)()()([]][))])` is a legal filename, yeah? You could cheat and assume an extension starting with a `.` character but seems presumptuous to me unless that's actually in the markdown spec (I'd be surprised if it is).

Comment: One option is to exclude matching the closing parenthesis when it is preceded by an opening one followed by 1+ digits `!\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)(?<!\(\d+)\)` https://regex101.com/r/U6FSOQ/1 You could also assert a non whitespace char after the closing parenthesis, but it will break when there is a space after the closing parenthesis in the filename itself `!\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)(?!\S)` Another way is to make the pattern a bit more specific `!\[(.*?)\]\((https?:\/\/\S+\.\w+)\)` https://regex101.com/r/iSypBa/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Your solution is right. please upload your answer to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be multiple ways to get the match from your example data.

One of the options could be to make the match a bit more specific matching non whitespace chars until the last occurrence of a dot, and then for example match 1+ word chars or match `png` literally followed by the closing parenthesis.

```
!\[(.*?)]\((https?:\/\/\S+\.\w+)\)
```

**Explanation**

- `!\[` Match `![`
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 1**, match any char except a newline, as least as possible
- `]\(` Match `](`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `https?:\/\/` Match the protocol with optional s followed by `://`
  - `\S+\.\w+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars, then the last dot and 1+ word chars
- `)\)` Close group 1 and match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v5IaWg/1)

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex:

```
//        (    $1           )    (     $2             )
//    ! [ (any char except \]) ] ( any char except \) )
//    |    |
//   \ /  \ /   

       

/\!\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^\)]*))/
```

Comment: If this solution doesn't work please comment why. Down voting without explanation is a little rude.